# How can I tell which frameworks are embedded in a given framework (Xcode 12)?

Tags: xcode, xcode12, carthage

How can I tell which frameworks are embedded in a given framework (Xcode 12)?

Like is there some kind of tool that you can use to introspect into a framework and see what other frameworks are in there?

Specifically, I'm interested to determine what gets adde if you run "carthage copy-frameworks" with no files specified in the input scripts. In our app there are a few places we do this, and it seems to be adding frameworks that weren't explicitly specified. I just want to know where they're being added.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just interested in the frameworks that are copied during compiltion you can have a look in 2 places:

1. The folder in which your app is built: `$HOME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<app-specific-id>/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/`.
2. Your built ap itself, which sits in the same folder I mentioned in 1.. You can right-click it and select `Show Package Contents`. Then under Frameworks you see all the frameworks linked to your app.

Get to your apps folder by opening `Xcode > Products` in the file naviagtor and select `Show in Finder` when right-click on your app there.